# TValueListEditor cell value is not getting refreshed

Tags: delphi, windows-7, refresh, cell, delphi-xe3

I'm having a problem where `TValueListEditor` cell value is not getting refreshed.
In the `OnStringsChange` event I'm changing the value of one cell based on the value of another cell.
In windows XP, it's working fine but where as in Windows 7, the `TValueListEditor` cell value is not getting refreshed.

I have tried calling the `TValueListEditor.refresh` method but it's still not working.

Can anyone give me the solution for this issue?

Comment: Do you have any code? Can you see the code?

Answer (score 0):

I have used `Valuelisteditor1.Invalidate` method, it will redraw the grid.
see the code,

```
procedure TForm1.ValueListEditor1StringsChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
 try
  if ValueListEditor1.Row = 1 then begin
  ValueListEditor1.Values['Foo3'] := ValuelistEditor1.Cells[1,1];
  Valuelisteditor1.Invalidate; //<<=== this redraws the grid properly
 end;
 finally
 end;
end;
```